# obtaining easy differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I passed by a question of a differential equation and i need help solving it thought its easy but am new with differential equations.

Let S be the solution of the differential equation :

$xy' -y= \frac{-x^2}{x^2+1}$. Deduce S.

i guess the first thing to do is to work out on  $xy' -y= 0$, is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Beside the method of  integrating factors, you also have the method of [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

As you say, the first thing is to solve the homegeneous equation. In you case, you then start with $x y'-y=0$ which leads to $y=C x$. But, for the complete equation, you consider that $C$ is a function of $x$.

Then $$x(C + C'x)-Cx=C'x^2=-\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$Which makes $$C'=-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$ Integrating gives $$C=-\tan^{-1}(x)+K$$ and finally $$y=Cx=-x \tan^{-1}(x)+K x$$

Answer (score 1):

the general form of first order linear differential equation is
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
so, your DE becomes
$$y'-\frac{1}{x}y=-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$
here
$$P(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$$
and
$$Q(x)=-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$
$$\rho=e^{\int P(x)dx}=e^{-\frac{1}{x}dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$
and
$$y.\rho=\int \rho.Q(x)dx$$
$$y.\frac{1}{x}=\int \frac{1}{x}(-\frac{x}{x^2+1})dx$$
$$y.\frac{1}{x}=-\tan^{-1}x+C_1$$
and then $$y=-x\tan^{-1}x+C_1x$$